# How can i Use drupal 8 CMI between two different sites?

Tags: 8, features, configuration

I think, normally the CMI works between cloned sites, not different sites. Is there any way to do that with CMI ? or still we hardly depends the features module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you are right, configuration management is for different instances of a same site. According to the [Drupal 8 CMI documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/administer/config),

> The Configuration Manager module in Drupal 8 provides a user interface
>   for importing and exporting configuration changes **between a Drupal
>   installation in different environments**, such as Development, Staging
>   and Production, so you can make and verify your changes with a
>   comfortable distance from your live environment.

The same idea appears in [this article](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/configuration-management-in-drupal-8-the-key-concepts),

> Perhaps the most important concept to understand is that the
>   configuration system is designed to optimize the process of moving
>   configuration between instances of the same site. **It is not intended
>   to allow exporting the configuration from one site to another**. In
>   order to move configuration data, the site and import files must have
>   matching values for UUID in the system.site configuration item. In
>   other words, additional environments should initially be set up as
>   clones of the site. We did not, for instance, hope to facilitate
>   exporting configuration from whitehouse.gov and importing it into
>   harvard.edu.